# What is the weather typically like on a cruise around Japan in October?

Tags: weather-and-climate, cruising, asia

I am planning to go on my honeymoon in October. Part of the honeymoon with be a cruise that leaves from Shanghai and goes to Japan and Korea. Has anyone been on a cruise around there? Does anyone know what the weather is typically like?

I looked up the average temp for Japan and Korea in October and it didn't sound great, but hoping that it is different in the ocean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

October in Japan is going to be a lot like October in Europe and America, namely **autumn**.  In Tokyo, [expect daytime highs around 20°C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokyo#Climate), mostly clear skies but occasional rain, beautiful autumn foliage.

Personally, late September/early October is one of my favorite seasons to be in Japan, second only to cherry blossom season around April.  Not too hot, not too cold, and off-peak so not too many tourists.  But if you're expecting beach weather, then sorry, you'll only find that at the southernmost tip around Okinawa...  and since Japan is a long and skinny country, there might already be a dusting of snow up in northern Hokkaido.

There's one catch though: October is the tail end of **typhoon season** in Japan, which could make a cruise pretty unpleasant (and explains the high precipitation readings on the chart linked to above).  However, the peak is Aug-Sep and the typhoons usually hit the Pacific side of the islands, not the Japan Sea side you'll presumably be sailing on, so odds are pretty high you'll be OK.

Comment: Thanks for the very details answer! Do you think the weather on the boat will be similar to on land?

Comment: Uhh...  yes?  (Why wouldn't it be?)